# Android database utility library

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Rather than have to rewrite a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` every time I want an app with a database component, I'm trying to make a database utility library project. Is this possible?

I call the class DBUtil. It `extends SQLiteOpenHelper`, overrides `onCreate` & `onUpgrade`, and has functions for inserting and selecting rows. It compiles to a jar file.

I include this jar file in another app, DBUtilTests, wherein I create the database, specifying the database name, give it table names and column names for each table. When I get to the part where I insert rows and then do a select to verify the rows are there, nothing is returned.

In the select function in DBUtil, the cursor object is always null for some reason. I've tried creating it both of the following ways:

1:

```
String tableName="whatever";
//getColumnNamesForTable is a local function that returns the column names 
// for a given table in an ArrayList of Strings
final ArrayList<String> columnNamesForTable = getColumnNamesForTable(tableName);
final String[] columns = columnNamesForTable.toArray(new String[columnNamesForTable.size()]);
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.query(tableName, columns, null, null, "", "", "");
```

2:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;    
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Is there anything wrong in the above code, and if not, is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: I made sure every time that I perform a database operation that returns a cursor object, I call close() on the cursor when I'm done reading data from it. Also, when I'm done with the database itself, I call close on the database. And there is only one instance of  DBUtil in DBUtilTests.

Comment: `query` and `rawQuery` never return `null`. This looks like a bug in the following code.